# Issue with Extending Editor to Highlight the Hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui, unity3d-editor

I'm extremely new to extending the Unity editor, and pieced together this script that highlights the selected object in the hierarchy. **The problem is, when I'm in the editor and the top of the stack(scene name) comes into view on the tree, the whole hierarchy turns invisible!** When I scroll down so the scene name goes out of view it fixes itself. I've attached images to give you a better idea of whats happening. This problem is minor when I have a bunch of objects, but would be unusable on a new scene.

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class HierarchyHighlighter
{
    static HierarchyHighlighter()
    {
        EditorApplication.hierarchyWindowItemOnGUI += HierarchyWindowItem_CB;
    }
    private static void HierarchyWindowItem_CB(int selectionID, Rect selectionRect)
    {
        Object o = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(selectionID);
        if ((o as GameObject).GetComponent<HierarchyHighlighterComponent>() != null)
        {
            HierarchyHighlighterComponent h = (o as GameObject).GetComponent<HierarchyHighlighterComponent>();
            if (h.highlight)
            {
                if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
                {
                    GUI.backgroundColor = h.color;
                    GUI.Box(selectionRect, "");
                    GUI.backgroundColor = Color.white;
                    EditorApplication.RepaintHierarchyWindow();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The console reads:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
HierarchyHighlighter.HierarchyWindowItem_CB(Int32 selectionID, Rect selectionRect) (at Assets/HierarchyHighlighter.cs:18)

Images:
[Functioning as normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOCLh.jpg)

[Not functioning as normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcsy5.jpg)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is throwing a null reference exception. I don't know which line is 18 because it's probably different in the file from what you posted, but my guess would be that `Object o = EditorUtility...` is returning null or that the object it returns isn't a GameObject so `(o as GameObject)` returns null and throws the exception when you call GetComponent.

There are also three obvious optimisations you could make:

- Only do the `(o as GameObject)` cast once. You don't even need o as an Object at all, so you could do the cast as soon as you get it: `GameObject o = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(selectionID) as GameObject;` (then null check o to fix the exception).
- Same for the GetComponent call: only do it once. `...Component h = o.GetComponent...`, then `if (h != null && h.highlight)`.
- Move `if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)` to the start of the function, otherwise you're wasting all this performance on every other gui event.

Also, use descriptive variable names. obj and highlighter would be much better than o and h.